# How to add swipe right to open navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, gesture

I have the standard navigation drawer, to open the navigation drawer you need to slide right from the left window. I tried this on diffrent phones and some who has shell on it you can't really slide right (pretty hard). So i want to add a swipe gesture. So when you slide right the drawer will open. I can't find the code to swipe!  I tried looking but everything seems blurry.

```
  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
```

Here is some of my code. Please tell me if you need anything else!! Hope someone can solve this!..

Update:
i have found the swipe code and made a class.

```js
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                } 
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Here is my usage of the code in my MainActivity class

```js
 drawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            }
        });
       drawer.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this ) {
            public boolean onSwipeTop() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            public boolean onSwipeRight() {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                return true;
            }
            public boolean onSwipeLeft() {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                return true;
            }
            public boolean onSwipeBottom() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The toast works when i swipe but i tried adding opendrawer and closerdrawer to right and left swipe, but nothing happends..

Comment: take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12938787/5923606

Comment: Ty it helped with finding the swipe gesture! But i can't seems to have the code open the navigation drawer? do you see if i'm missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

change the methods from

```
public void onSwipeRight() {
    }
```

to

```
public abstract void onSwipeRight();
```

...

and make ur class abstract too

```
public abstract class OnSwipeTouchListener
```

Comment: Ty for you help! I will try immediatley when i come home from work!